# Need some advice with a simple C code program

Tags: c

I have a question with C. I just started learning it so bear with me.

I want to write a simple program to:

> 1. Handle errors
> 2. Do a simple print task

It's just made in a console.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
   int x, y, z, loop_one, loop_two;
   printf("Give a number \n");
   scanf("%d",&x);
   for(loop_one = 1; loop_one <= x; loop_one += 1)
   {
      for(loop_two = 1; loop_two <= x; loop_two += 1)
      {
         y = y + 1;
         printf("1/%d = ", y);
      }
   }
}
```

This is my code but now I'm a bit lost with the logic.  I didn't even add error handling.

The errors should be whenever the user types a negative number. It should print "retype" and continue doing it till the user give a positive number.

The second task is that the program needs to calculate from **1/1 + 1/2 .... 1/x = sum** and print it like this.

For example if the user give 5, the output should be:

```
1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 = 2.28
```

Comment: You need a new source of learning C, your current one is very outdated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() /*main is a function that returns int*/
{

float x,y,loop_one;/*use float instead of int so you don't lose data */

x = -1;/*set x to be a neg number */

y = 0; /*if not init y = garbage */

while(x < 0)

{

    printf("Give a number \n");

    scanf("%f",&x); /*must advise not to use scanf as it is an unsafe function */
}
for(loop_one=1;loop_one<=x;loop_one+=1) /*you only need one for loop*/
{
    y += (1/loop_one);/*which is the same as y = y+(1/loop_one)*/

    if(loop_one != x)

    {

        printf("1/%.0f + ",loop_one);/*%.0f asks to print none after dec point */

    }

    else

    {

        printf("1/%.0f  ",loop_one); 

    }

}

printf(" = %.2f\n", y);/*%.2f asks to print 2 values after dec point */

return 0;  /*on success returns 0*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int x,y,z,loop_one,loop_two;
printf("Give a number: ");
scanf("%d",&x);
float ans=0;
for(loop_one=1;loop_one<x;loop_one+=1)
{
    ans+=1/(float)loop_one;
    printf("1/%d + ",loop_one);

}
ans+=1/(float)x;
printf("1/%d = %f\n",x,ans);
}
```

You actually don't need two loops for calculating the final value.

I've terminated the loop just before x otherwise it would had printed an extra " + "
sign just after 1/x.

If you don't know about typecasting(i.e (float)x) you may google it.
In C division on integers always returns an integer ,
hence 1/2 +1/3 +1/4 is 0 in C!

Therefore integers have been converted to floats

Now to handle -ve integers

You may take a look at this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int x,y,z,loop_one,loop_two;
printf("Give a number: ");
scanf("%d",&x);
while(x<=0)
{
    printf("Error !, Enter a valid number: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
}
float ans=0;
for(loop_one=1;loop_one<x;loop_one+=1)
{
    ans+=1/(float)loop_one;
    printf("1/%d + ",loop_one);

}
ans+=1/(float)x;
printf("1/%d = %f\n",x,ans);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main function should always be either `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, depending on whether you are interested in command-line arguments or not. Always `#include <stdlib>`, so you can return from your main function using `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` or `return EXIT_FAILURE;`, or exit the program anywhere using `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);` or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`.

The recommended simplest "Hello, world!" program is

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Use it as the basis of your own programs.

> 1. Handle errors

The [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) family of functions returns the number of successful conversions. So, you really should have something like

```
    if (scanf("%d", &x) < 1) {
        printf("That's not a number. Goodbye, you sneaky human.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

to check if the input was an integer or not.

Hint: Try

```
    printf("Please input a positive integer:\n");
    while ( (scanf("%d", &x) < 1) || (x < 1) ) {
        printf("No, a positive integer, please.\n");
    }
```

and see how it behaves.  The `||` is a logical OR operator in C. It is short-circuiting, meaning that the left side is evaluated first, and if it is true, the right side won't be examined at all.

> 2. Do a simple print task

Learn to doodle the logic on paper first. You'll soon learn how to do it in your head, although doodling is useful for many, due to how the hand-eye coordination affects the thought model involved. Some use the Rubber Duck method instead, i.e. talk it aloud, as if describing it to some other person (but talk to eg. a rubber duck instead); putting the thoughts into words and linear speech helps organize your thoughts as well.

[Pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode) is often a useful method of doodling it out. In this case, we could describe the input part as

```
Let  n  be some integer
Prompt user to input a positive integer
Scan n from input
While scan failed, or n is less than 1:
    Prompt user to input a positive integer
End While
```

The print-out part we could write as

```
Let  sum  be some double-precision floating-point number
Let  i  be some integer

Let  sum = 1.0
Print "1/1"
For i from 2 to n, inclusive:
    Print " + 1 / %d", i
    Let  sum = sum + 1.0 / i
End For

Print " = %.3f\n", sum
```

When adding each fraction to the sum, we use `1.0 / i`, because we want to evaluate it as a floating-point division. (We could use `1/(double)i`, or `1.0 / (double)i`, instead; but as long as one (either dividend or divisor) is a floating-point number, then the compiler will do a floating-point division.)  If we only use `1/i`, the compiler does *integer division*, which yields 0 for all `i` greater than one. That's not what we want.

When printing out the result, `%f` is the pattern to use with a floating-point number. The `%.3f` form tells the C library to use three decimals after the decimal point, so for example `printf("%.3f\n", 1.0)` prints `1.000`. The `\n`, as you well know by now, is a newline: any following output will go to a new line.

You've got ample help now to complete the assignment. Don't be a nasty human and try and <kbd>copy</kbd>+<kbd>paste</kbd> the answer from somewhere; take the effort to learn this stuff, and you'll find you have a powerful set of tools at your fingertips to solve many different types of problems, and have fun while at it. Good luck!